# Bootstrap4 Custom CSS with SASS

Tags: css, sass, twitter-bootstrap-4

I'm currently trying to evaluate bs4-alpha and I want to load a custom css (e.g. chaning default font-size). I added a bootstrap-custom.css and added a `<script>` tag to my `<head>` section, however when firing up the application the changes are not stored. Instead everything goes into the `_reboot.scss`. I read something about altering a `_custom.scss` which is supposed to be shipped with bs4, which it wasn't. How am I supposed to load custom CSS into my bs4 application?

Comment: Did you mean `<link>` instead of `<script>`? I'd concatenate custom CSS after Bootstrap one or load them "statically" with 2 `<link>` if it's more perf (a huge resource may be split in 2 or 3 and achieve better webperf, depends) but if you want to load it dynamically, [Filament group loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/) is an excellent resource

Comment: Oh yes of course `<link>`. Well yes I load them after the bootstrap one, so the order they get loaded in is:

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/resource/themes/default/css/bootstrap4/bootstrap.min.css"/>`

`<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/resource/themes/mycss/css/bootstrap-customized.css"/>`

Comment: There is a [`_custom.scss`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_custom.scss), to be copied from `_variables.scss`. You can then modify [`$font-size-base`](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss#L248) (keeping a relative unit like rem is WAY better). Reading comment in `_variables.scss`, I fail to see why it's better to modify `_custom.scss` then `_variables.scss` as it's _also_ versioned but well... The comment in `_custom.scss` seems OK though

Comment: So the only way to do this is rebuilding the whole package? Does that mean every time I do a minor change to my css the whole package needs to be rebuilt?

Comment: If you want to modifiy the default font size of BS, you'll have to compile it once (and after each update of BS, if you update it during the life of the project). Everything that is in your 2nd CSS/Sass file doesn't have to: it can be standard CSS. What would seem complicated to me is if you're using Bootstrap already compiled with default values and then in a 2nd stylesheet modifying a lot of basic styles. It'll work better with BS4 then old BS using pixels as unit but still, I guess they won't coexist nicely.